# Attempting to omit one checkbox control in a loop

Tags: c#, controls

I have a utitility class that has a static method which takes a control object as a parameter.  The reason for the class/method is to clear/reset the form of the application for the next new game.

I do a bunch of stuff to all the different controls and for the checkbox controls, I removed the checkmark.  There is one checkbox that I don't want to touch (leave it checked if it is).  I had it working, and somehow I can't remember and it is probably very simple.

Current code:

```
// Called when a new game is started.  Clears all checkmarks in all checkbox controls

if (control is CheckBox)
{
   CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)control;
   checkBox.Checked = false;
}
```

test code:

```
// Called when a new game is started.  Clears all checkmarks in all checkbox controls

if (control is CheckBox)
{
   if (control is form.checkBoxWarning)
   {
      continue;
   }

   CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)control;
   checkBox.Checked = false;
}
```

'form' is passed to this static class:

```
public static void ResetAllControls(Control form)
```

but I still can't figure how to bring that control into context.  The control name I am trying is checkBoxWarning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want is this:

```
if (control is CheckBox)
{
    if (control.Name == "checkBoxWarning")
    {
         continue;
    }
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)control;
    checkBox.Checked = false;
}
```

However, the better way to do it is to use the [Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx) property. Set it to `false` on any checkbox you don't want touched, then use this code:

```
if (control is CheckBox)
{
    if (control.Tag != null && ((bool)control.Tag) == false)
    {
        continue;
    }
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)control;
    checkBox.Checked = false;
}
```

Doing it this way will allow you to make it so that multiple checkboxes can be untouched, without ever having to touch your class code again.

Comment: @HighCore -- Sometimes you get stuck with these things. Believe it or not, at my job, I still maintain a program that was written in .NET 1.1. Talk about horrible! No generics, no Linq!

Comment: **Solution:** Right click project -> Properties -> Change target Framework to 4.5 -> Compile -> Fix compile errors -> PROFIT. No need for dinosaur stuff.